# Почему Json сохраняется пустым?

Tags: c#

Учусь пользоваться библиотекой

Почему Json сохраняется пустым ?

Тело Json файла такое `{}`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp4TestJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SohranenenieVJson();

        }

        private static async void SohranenenieVJson() 
        {

            Users users = new Users();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                User user = new User();

                users.usersList.Add(user);
            }

            using FileStream createStream = File.Create("users.json");
            await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(createStream, users);
        }
    }


    class User 
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Age { get; private set; }

        public User()
        {

            Name = "Артём";
            Age = "20";
        }
    }

    class Users
    {

        public List<User> usersList;

        public Users()
        {

            usersList = new List<User>();

        }
    }
}
```

**MSDN**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** - после комментария [@EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD - 2**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD - 3**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123649/discussion-on-question-by-vipz--json--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET Core 3.1 вы не сможете сериализовать поля с помощью `System.Text.Json`.

`JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields` [поддерживается](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-5.0) только начиная с .NET 5.

Советую использовать свойство

```cs
public List<User> UsersList { get; private set; }
```

На выходе

```json
{"UsersList":[{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"},{"Name":"\u0410\u0440\u0442\u0451\u043C","Age":"20"}]}
```

А если сериализовать вот так

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(createStream, users, options);
```

То на выходе получится вот так

```json
{
  "UsersList": [
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Артём",
      "Age": "20"
    }
  ]
}
```